# Flutter Add List to List

Tags: flutter, list, addition

I tried to add a List to a List in Flutter but it doesn't add it and just pops the context.
It should be added to it that I can get the list items and gridview them.
The List is a separate file in a class called `"DeviceList"` and the function with the if is in an Stateful widget.

That's my list:

```
class DeviceList {
  /*
    [
      DeviceName [String],
      IconPath [String],
      SwitchTextOn [String],
      SwitchTextOff [String],
      SwitchIconOn [Icondata],
      SwitchIconOff [Icondata],
    ]
  */

  static List devices = [
    [
      "Lamp",
      "assets/icons/lamp.png",
      "On",
      "Off",
      CupertinoIcons.sun_max,
      CupertinoIcons.moon,
    ],
  ];
}
```

That's the code to add

```
      if (_deviceClassController.text == "Licht") {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.pop(context);
        String path = "assets/icons/lamp.png";
        IconData iconOn = CupertinoIcons.sun_max;
        IconData iconOff = CupertinoIcons.moon;
        DeviceList.devices.add(
          [
            _deviceNameController.text,
            path,
            "On".tr,
            "Off".tr,
            iconOn,
            iconOff,
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: I will prefer operation 1st, then pop on last line.